# How do I extract only the first time a key/value pair exists in a json object in bash with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Can anyone help me using `bash` and `jq` to be able to filter this JSON down to only the first occurrence of the `user.login` for each item, with the highest `submitted_at` key. An endpoint is giving me back historical information and I only want the most up to date details for the response. Take for example this JSON

```json
[
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user1",
    },
    "state": "CHANGE_REQUESTED",
    "submitted_at": "2024-01-23T19:18:31Z",
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user1",
    },
    "state": "DISMISSED",
    "submitted_at": "2024-02-05T16:49:58Z",
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user1",
    },
    "state": "APPROVED"
    "submitted_at": "2024-02-06T19:18:31Z",
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user2",
    },
    "state": "APPROVED"
    "submitted_at": "2024-01-23T19:18:31Z",
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user2",
    },
    "state": "DISMISSED"
    "submitted_at": "2024-01-21T19:18:31Z",
  }
]
```

The result should be the following JSON with only the most recent duplicate of `user.login` that I can then loop over

```json
[
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user1",
    },
    "state": "APPROVED"
    "submitted_at": "2024-02-06T19:18:31Z",
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "login": "user2",
    },
    "state": "APPROVED"
    "submitted_at": "2024-01-23T19:18:31Z",
  }
]
```

After which I can loop through in bash to gather the information that I need from the object.

This may be answered already somewhere but I think I'm struggling to word the ask in a search engine to be able to get the desired result.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up figuring it out on jqplay.org using the following query `. |= sort_by(.submitted_at) | reverse | unique_by(.user.login)` I was originally trying to do it using groups and selects, but now I found the unique by and after a sort it works nicely. I'll likely just delete this.

Comment: I'd add your own answer because it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> only the first occurrence of the `user.login` for each item, with the highest `submitted_at` key

With `group_by(.user.login)` you can group together into subarrays all objects with the same `.user.login` value. Then, from each subarray, pick the one item with the highest `.submitted_at` value using `max_by(.submitted_at)`. The final array can be created either using an array constructor `[…]` and iterating over the groups using `.[]`, or by re-using the grouping array and accessing the groups using a `map`.

```bash
# Using an array constructor
[group_by(.user.login)[] | max_by(.submitted_at)]

# Using map
group_by(.user.login) | map(max_by(.submitted_at))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3UVgIOb7LyP)

Answer (score 0):

In order to result in the JSON that I was expecting, I used the following jq statement.

`jq '. |= sort_by(.submitted_at) | reverse | unique_by(.user.login)' "$tmp_response_file_pr_reviews_request"`

This sorted the resulting array by it's `submitted_at` revered so that the highest date is at the top, and then using `unique_by` to filter down to only the first instance of each `user.login Key-Value pair in the array, resulting in what I needed.

Comment: You can omit `. |=` as it's always the full context that is updated, if not further specified.